# Jenkins build failure when run as a windows service

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

Unable to successfully build a jenkins job when the jenkins is run as a windows service. these are steps I followed-

1) ran java -jar jenkins.war from cmd

2) navigated to 'install as a windows service' under manage jenkins and created jenkins service under services.msc.

3) closed the cmd (through which the jenkins war file was initially run)

4) created a maven project and tried code from local pom location as well as from the bit bucket.

5) executed via clean install goals and options

result- build unstable. browser did not launch and tests failed.

any help much appreciated.

```
Results when build with code supplied from local pom file
Results :

Tests in error: 
  Then Login is successful(Scenario: Verify that login is successful with valid username and password): Expected condition failed: waiting for text ('DASHBOARD') to be present in element found by By.id: menutitle (tried for 10 second(s) with 3 SECONDS interval)(..)
  Scenario: Verify that login is successful with valid username and password: Expected condition failed: waiting for text ('DASHBOARD') to be present in element found by By.id: menutitle (tried for 10 second(s) with 3 SECONDS interval)(..)

Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\Test_analysis\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ NxTier ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\Test_analysis\target\NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ NxTier ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\Test_analysis\target\NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository\aBILLity\NxTier\1.0-SNAPSHOT\NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\Test_analysis\pom.xml to C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository\aBILLity\NxTier\1.0-SNAPSHOT\NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.212 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-16T13:58:55+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/311M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\Test_analysis\pom.xml to aBILLity/NxTier/1.0-SNAPSHOT/NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\Test_analysis\target\NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to aBILLity/NxTier/1.0-SNAPSHOT/NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
channel stopped
Finished: UNSTABL
```

Comment: Can you please provide relevant log output? Is there an error message?

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply. i have edited my initial post to include the error message. thanks once again!